# XAMPP 7.0.0 php session causing whole page not to load

Tags: php, session, xampp

Before upgrading to XAMPP 7, everything used to work fine.

Then after the update, everything except php sessions is working.

Any page with `session_start()` does not load in the browser and nothing is logged into php.log file concerning the error.

I've looked everywhere for such, and I found one here on Stackoverflow that had a similar problem, but the issue had been using MySQL.

Now, at the very basic level, this won't load:

```
<?php
   session_start();
?>
```

I've tried changing the `session.save_path` in `php.ini` file without any success. Any help?

Comment: It does works exactly as it should in xampp 7 for me, can you be more clearer?

Comment: have you checked the rest of your code for php7 backward-compatibility breaks? are you sure its actually that thats breaking?

Comment: I'm unsure how I should clarify. I actually saved a php file that had `<?php session_start (); ?>` without anything else and it the page couldn't be loaded in the browser. But when I removed `session_start()` from the page, it loaded fine.then when I put on `session.auto_start`, none of the pages could load.